# why Enable changed to true in function?

Tags: c#, function, controls

i make a function that uses a control as a parameter, and i use the control's property 'enable'.

the problem is that the control have Enable=false and inside the function it's true,

any ideas why?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    try
    {
    ...

    Shared.DrawTextByAlignment(pevent.Graphics, this, this.TextAlign);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Button:OnPaint\n" + ex.Message); 
}
```

---

```
static public void DrawTextByAlignment(Graphics g, Control myControl, ContentAlignment TextAlign)
{
    ...

    Brush myBrush;
    if (myControl.Enabled) myBrush = new SolidBrush(myControl.ForeColor);
    else myBrush = Brushes.Gray;            

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi - we're going to need some code and the type of control that you're using please

Comment: Hi, can you share with us the method you are talking about?

Comment: Can you show the code of your function? When does Enabled==false and when does it change to true? Try debugging your app and inspecting Enabled property at various times to see when it changes value.

Comment: Set a debug breakpoint on the setter for the control's property. Allowing you to see what is touching the value.

Comment: i wrote this question **after** debugging. the enable property does'nt realy changes just in the copy of the control that the function created

Comment: @unicorn - you are passing a **reference** to the control; there **is** no "copy of the control".

Comment: that information makes the problom wierder

Comment: I still ony see 1 check of Enabled...

Comment: that because there is only one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you derive a class from Control and override the Enabled property using the new keyword, your function will still access Control.Enabled. Change the signature to

```
static public void DrawTextByAlignment(..., MyControl myControl, ...)
```

Comment: i want it to bo generic, so i can do it with any of my controls, without create new funtion for each

Comment: @unicorn - then maybe it's better not to override Enabled and instead e.g. handle the EnabledChanged event. Show the code of your implementation of Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a control, you are almost universally talking about a `class` / object-instance, so all you are passing is the *reference* to the control - the control itself is identical.

One *possible* cause of this is an incorrect check:

```
if(ctrl.Enabled = true) { // spot the assignment!
    DoSomething(ctrl);
}
```

which should be:

```
if(ctrl.Enabled == true) {
    DoSomething(ctrl);
}
```

or just:

```
if(ctrl.Enabled) {
    DoSomething(ctrl);
}
```

but the compiler would tell you that in a warning...

> Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = ?

This leaves only a few options:

- the `Enabled` has genuinely changed, perhaps due to a state-change such as moving it in a control tree
- the `Enabled` property defies all sanity and changes upon inspection
- the `Enabled` property is thread-specific and you are talking to it from multiple threads
- or, there is something else going on in your code that your question doesn't tell us, but the source might

I rather expect it to be the last option...

Comment: @unicorn that edit doesn't allow me to see **anything** related to your 2 checks on `Enabled`, nor how that method is being invoked. In short, that tells me nothing except "you have a method called `DrawTextByAlignment`"

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be need Visible property instead on enabled property.

Because Enable = false the control does not create any changes